# What would be a good way to add a compiler to your program for runtime compiling?

Tags: c++, compilation

I want to make a c++ program where it **compiles user written c++ source code** into a DLL and then at runtime links the **user created DLL** back into the program.

An example of this is how unreal engine can compile the game and then immediately run it inside the editor.

What would be a good option for compiling user's source code into DLLs. Would i be able to use GNU gcc for this?

Comment: Nice try, but too broad.

Comment: sigh, well i dont know how to really narrow it down further.

Comment: This really is both a large and deep topic, there are too many strategies and solutions available. Maybe check [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)?

Comment: Sounds like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the backstory that led to this implementation decision?

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look into what LLVM could offer my project.

Comment: @GameHog - "How do I do X?" is almost always to broad. It should be "I have tried to do X this way (show code), but have a specific problem".

Comment: @MrEricSir i decided i wanted to take a crack at making my own game creator but 2d. But i need to have a compiler i can either built in. The user installs it. or it comes prepackaged.

Comment: This isn't "how do I do X", it's "is it possible to do X with Y".

Comment: You're probably better off integrating a scripting engine. For example, the Love2D engine uses Lua scripts for game logic.

Comment: Really easy, use the `system` function.  The `system` function will allow you to execute programs, like compilers.  The big issues is installing the compiler and its supporting files, into the target platform along with your executable.  This will increase the size of your installer by many orders of magnitude (look at the size of the GNU C++ compiler and its supporting files).  Also, observe the licensing agreement for the compiler. IMO, you don't want this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any compiler you want -- whatever works best on your target platform(s).

Comment: Come on, is this answer really necessary?

Comment: I understood the question to be asking if there were any special conditions or requirements on doing so, and the answer to that is "no", any compiler that supports the platform will work. Perhaps I misunderstood the question. What do you think it's asking?

Comment: I think what it's asking is too broad to be answered, as I right out said in my first comment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "*Can GCC, or another compiler, be used to compile a DLL that's then loaded by the program that executed the compiler?*" seems reasonably narrow and answerable to me.